# Is it possible to load google photos metadata into google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apis-explorer, google-photos-api

I have a project where I have scanned 10,000 family pictures from as far back as the 1900's and I am organizing them in Google Photos. I have a spreadsheet where I was keeping track of the proper dates and captions for the entire collection. I would organize a few at a time but then recently found out about the google photos API.

I would like to use something like the methods [Method: mediaItems.list](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/list?authuser=0) or [Method: mediaItems.search](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/search?authuser=0) to get the data from my photos into the spreadsheet to manage.

The output from these examples is exactly what I'm looking for and would want to load that into a spreadsheet.

It would be super awesome if there was a way to update back from the sheet again as well.

I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063937/0auth2-problem-to-get-my-google-photos-libraries-in-a-google-sheet-of-mine) but the code provided does not work for me.

I have this function now in my sheet

```
function photoAPI() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var albums_sh = ss.getSheetByName("albums") || ss.insertSheet("albums", ss.getSheets().length); 
  albums_sh.clear();
  var narray = []; 

  var api = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums";
  var headers = { "Authorization": "Bearer " +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() };
  var options = { "headers": headers, "method" : "GET", "muteHttpExceptions": true };

  var param= "", nexttoken;
  do {
    if (nexttoken)
      param = "?pageToken=" + nexttoken; 
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api + param, options);
    var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    json.albums.forEach(function (album) {
      var data = [
        album.title,
        album.mediaItemsCount,
        album.productUrl
      ];
      narray.push(data);
    });
    nexttoken = json.nextPageToken;
  } while (nexttoken);
  albums_sh.getRange(1, 1, narray.length, narray[0].length).setValues(narray);
}
```

When I run it in debug mode, I get the following error

> ({error:{code:403, message:"Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", status:"PERMISSION_DENIED"}})

I know this means I need to authenticate but don't know how to make that happen.

I have an API key and a secret from the Google photos API pages.

**Edit**
I used the links from @Tanaike to figure out how to add scopes to my project. 
I added these three.

- spreadsheets.currentonly
- photoslibrary
- script.external_request

Now when I run in debug mode, I get a 403 error indicating I need to set up my API. Summary of the error is below:

> error:
>   code:403
>   Photos Library API has not been used in project 130931490217 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting 
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/photoslibrary.googleapis.com/overview?project=130931490217
>   Google developers console API activation
>   type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help
>   "PERMISSION_DENIED"

When I try to go to the listed URL though, I just get a message that says "Failed to load."

Comment: Can you confirm whether the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary` is included in the scopes in `appsscript.json` of your project? The references are [this](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/albums/list) and [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests).

Comment: Have you had a look here to see if any of the answers provide a working solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51271207

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for those references. I now have the scope set in `appsscript.json` for `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary` I now have a different issue, I'll add details to the main question.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Thanks for the link. After the help from Tanaike I think your suggestion may be what I need to do next. I'm still confused how to connect these all together though. I have oauth credentials but the other question indicates the credentials needed may be from a different source than I think they are. I also don't know where to put credentials in my current code. Is that what I'm missing?

Comment: @Isaac Guerrero Thank you for replying. If you are using the standalone script or the container-bound script which was created after April 8, 2019, I think that the reason of your new issue is that Cloud Platform Project and Google Apps Script Project are not linked. Please link them. The reference is [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects).

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you! this last link was exactly what I needed. Once I switched my script project to use a standard GCP project everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my code working with the help of @Tanaike in my comments above. I had two issues.

1) I needed to specify the oauthScopes in appsscript.json which is hidden by default in google scripts. It can be revealed by going to the menu and selecting View > Show Manifest File.

2) I was using a default GCP project which did not have authorization to use the photos API and could not be enabled. I needed to switch to a standard GCP project which I had created earlier and had enabled the photos API.

Here is my original posted function with additional comments after I got it working:

```
function photoAPI_ListAlbums() {
  // Modified from code by Stackoverflow user Frç Ju at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063937/0auth2-problem-to-get-my-google-photos-libraries-in-a-google-sheet-of-mine
  // which was originally Modified from http://ctrlq.org/code/20068-blogger-api-with-google-apps-script

  /*
  This function retrieves all albums from your personal google photos account and lists each one with the name of album, count of photos, and URL in a new sheet.

  Requires Oauth scopes. Add the below line to appsscript.json
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]

  Also requires a standard GCP project with the appropriate Photo APIs enabled.
  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects
  */

  //Get the spreadsheet object
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Check for presence of target sheet, if it does not exist, create one.
  var albums_sh = ss.getSheetByName("albums") || ss.insertSheet("albums", ss.getSheets().length); 
  //Make sure the target sheet is empty
  albums_sh.clear();
  var narray = []; 

  //Build the request string. Default page size is 20, max 50. set to max for speed.
  var api = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums?pageSize=50";
  var headers = { "Authorization": "Bearer " +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() };
  var options = { "headers": headers, "method" : "GET", "muteHttpExceptions": true };

  var param= "", nexttoken;

  //Make the first row a title row
  var data = [
    "Title",
    "Item Count",
    "ID",
    "URL"
  ];
  narray.push(data);

  //Loop through JSON results until a nextPageToken is not returned indicating end of data
  do {
    //If there is a nextpagetoken, add it to the end of the request string
    if (nexttoken)
      param = "&pageToken=" + nexttoken; 

    //Get data and load it into a JSON object
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api + param, options);
    var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    //Loop through the JSON object adding desired data to the spreadsheet.
    json.albums.forEach(function (album) {
      var data = [
        "'"+album.title,  //The prepended apostrophe makes albums with a name such as "June 2007" to show up as that text rather than parse as a date in the sheet.
        album.mediaItemsCount,
        album.id,
        album.productUrl
      ];
      narray.push(data);
    });

    //Get the nextPageToken
    nexttoken = json.nextPageToken;
    //Continue if the nextPageToaken is not null
  } while (nexttoken);

  //Save all the data to the spreadsheet.
  albums_sh.getRange(1, 1, narray.length, narray[0].length).setValues(narray);
}
```

And here is another function which I created in the same style to pull photo metadata directly. This is what I was originally trying to accomplish.

```
function photoAPI_ListPhotos() {
  //Modified from above function photoAPI_ListAlbums

  /*
  This function retrieves all photos from your personal google photos account and lists each one with the Filename, Caption, Create time (formatted for Sheet), Width, Height, and URL in a new sheet.
  it will not include archived photos which can be confusing if you happen to have a large chunk of archived photos some pages may return only a next page token with no media items.

  Requires Oauth scopes. Add the below line to appsscript.json
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]

  Also requires a standard GCP project with the appropriate Photo APIs enabled.
  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects
  */

  //Get the spreadsheet object
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Check for presence of target sheet, if it does not exist, create one.
  var photos_sh = ss.getSheetByName("photos") || ss.insertSheet("photos", ss.getSheets().length); 
  //Make sure the target sheet is empty
  photos_sh.clear();
  var narray = []; 

  //Build the request string. Max page size is 100. set to max for speed.
  var api = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems?pageSize=100";
  var headers = { "Authorization": "Bearer " +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() };
  var options = { "headers": headers, "method" : "GET", "muteHttpExceptions": true };

  //This variable is used if you want to resume the scrape at some page other than the start. This is needed if you have more than 40,000 photos.
  //Uncomment the line below and add the next page token for where you want to start in the quotes.
  //var nexttoken="";

  var param= "", nexttoken;
  //Start counting how many pages have been processed.
  var pagecount=0;

  //Make the first row a title row
  var data = [
    "Filename",
    "description",
    "Create Time",
    "Width",
    "Height",
    "ID",
    "URL",
    "NextPage"
  ];
  narray.push(data);

  //Loop through JSON results until a nextPageToken is not returned indicating end of data
  do {
    //If there is a nextpagetoken, add it to the end of the request string
    if (nexttoken)
      param = "&pageToken=" + nexttoken; 

    //Get data and load it into a JSON object
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api + param, options);
    var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    //Check if there are mediaItems to process.
    if (typeof json.mediaItems === 'undefined') {
      //If there are no mediaItems, Add a blank line in the sheet with the returned nextpagetoken

      //var data = ["","","","","","","",json.nextPageToken];
      //narray.push(data);
    } else {
      //Loop through the JSON object adding desired data to the spreadsheet.
      json.mediaItems.forEach(function (MediaItem) {

        //Check if the mediaitem has a description (caption) and make that cell blank if it is not present.
        if(typeof MediaItem.description === 'undefined') {
            var description = "";
          } else {
            var description = MediaItem.description;
          }

        //Format the create date as appropriate for spreadsheets.
        var d = new Date(MediaItem.mediaMetadata.creationTime);

        var data = [
          MediaItem.filename,
          "'"+description, //The prepended apostrophe makes captions that are dates or numbers save in the sheet as a string. 
          d,
          MediaItem.mediaMetadata.width,
          MediaItem.mediaMetadata.height,
          MediaItem.id,
          MediaItem.productUrl,
          json.nextPageToken
        ];
        narray.push(data);
      });
    }

    //Get the nextPageToken
    nexttoken = json.nextPageToken;    

    pagecount++;
    //Continue if the nextPageToaken is not null
    //Also stop if you reach 400 pages processed, this prevents the script from timing out. You will need to resume manually using the nexttoken variable above.
  } while (pagecount<400 && nexttoken);

    //Continue if the nextPageToaken is not null (This is commented out as an alternative and can be used if you have a small enough collection it will not time out.)
  //} while (nexttoken);

  //Save all the data to the spreadsheet.
  photos_sh.getRange(1, 1, narray.length, narray[0].length).setValues(narray);
}
```

Because of the limitations of the ListPhotos function and the fact that my library is so enormous, I am still working on a third function to pull photo metadata from all the photos in specific albums. I'll edit this answer once I pull that off.

Comment: Great explanation, i was just checking how do we add a new google project in the manifest file, because you have mentioned that you created a new GCP project, but did you add that to the manifest file?